# Website nginx flooded with no such file or directory request with a strange request, how do I block them?

Tags: wordpress, security, nginx, redirect

so checking the website logs I've found 2000 requests x day, with different base URL but 2 different type of ending string, here the examples:
`*var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/random-slug/*],thor-cookies,div.cookie-alert,div.cookie-banner,div.cookie-consent,div.cookie-content,div.cookie-layer,div.cookie-notice,div.cookie-notification,div.cookie-overlay,div.cookieHolder,div.cookies-visible,div.gdpr,div.js-disclaimer,div.privacy-notice,div.with-cookie,.as-oil-content-overlay`

Second one:
`*var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/random-slug/*],sibbo-cmp-layout,thor-cookies,div.cookie-alert,div.cookie-banner,div.cookie-consent,div.cookie-consent-popup,div.cookie-content,div.cookie-layer,div.cookie-notice,div.cookie-notification,div.cookie-overlay,div.cookie-wrapper,div.cookieHolder,div.cookies-modal-container,div.cookies-visible,div.gdpr,div.js-disclaimer,div.privacy-notice,div.v-cookie,div.with-cookie,.as-oil-content-overlay,`

I tried to google them, and I found random website like Binance, from the content the string it seems to be referring to an overlay for cookie consent, but I don't have one on my website, so I'm wondering why I get this many requests all **failed (2: No such file or directory)**

So I'm wondering if anyone knows what is this, and if I can block directly requests like those 2 to avoid getting the nginx errors flooded with them.

I tried to search around for a solution, the only thing that came in mind was to do a nginx redirect that returns 410 error, but this case is particular because that **]** that divide the slug and the file not found, I don't know how to do it, and actually if I go to that URL the page actually works, so a better redirect would be to the slug directly before the bracket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some cybercriminal, or probably just a [script kiddie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie), sending probe URLs to sites on every IP address they can think of, looking for servers that might be vulnerable to some exploit or other.

All public-facing web sites get some of this garbage. You can't make it go away, unfortunately. It's almost as old as the web, but considerably stupider.

You CAN keep your software up to date so it's not YOUR site where they find a vulnerability.